# Why can't I declare an NSFetchResultsController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using Xcode version 8.0 beta 6. I'm trying to declare fetch results controller but it keeps showing up an error 
"Reference to generic type "NSFetchedResultsController" requires arguments in <...>

```
   var fetchedResultsController : NSFetchedResultsController!
```

Xcode is suggesting that I fix it by using

```
var fetchedResultsController : NSFetchedResultsController<AnyObject>!
```

which also throws an error "Type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'NSFetchRequestResult'

Comment: @PetahChristian yeah that solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here's how I usually declare mine:

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Friend")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "lastMessage.timestamp", ascending: false)]
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "lastMessage.timestamp != nil")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    frc.delegate = self
    return frc

}()
```